# How can I synchronize a List like a SyncVar in Unity?

Tags: c#, network-programming, unity-game-engine

I want to synchronize a `List` across the network like when using the `SyncVar` attribute in Unity. Is that possible to do?

When we write a class that extends `NetworkBehaviour` it allows us to use `SyncVar` on variables:

```
[SyncVar(hook = "OnHealthChange")]
public int currentHealth = maxHealth;
```

In same way is it possible to do something similar with a `List`? This doesn't work:

```
[SyncVar(hook = "TimeDiff")]
public List<RoomPlayerInfo> listRoomPlayerInfo = new List<RoomPlayerInfo> ();
```

I tried that line of code but it showed me the following error in console:

> Error 1: UNetWeaver error: SyncVar
>   [System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>   GameManager::listRoomPlayerInfo] cannot have generic parameters.
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) Unity.UNetWeaver.Log:Error(String)
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/Program.cs:20)
>   Unity.UNetWeaver.NetworkBehaviourProcessor:ProcessSyncVars() (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetBehaviourProcessor.cs:1838)
>   Unity.UNetWeaver.NetworkBehaviourProcessor:Process() (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetBehaviourProcessor.cs:53)
>   Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:ProcessNetworkBehaviourType(TypeDefinition)
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1064)
>   Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:CheckNetworkBehaviour(TypeDefinition) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1549)
>   Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:Weave(String, IEnumerable`1,
>   IAssemblyResolver, String, String, String) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1658)
>   Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:WeaveAssemblies(IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1,
>   IAssemblyResolver, String, String, String) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1748)
>   Unity.UNetWeaver.Program:Process(String, String, String, String[],
>   String[], IAssemblyResolver, Action`1, Action`1) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/Program.cs:34)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.Serialization.Weaver:WeaveUnetFromEditor(String,
>   String, String, String, Boolean)
>
> Error2: Failure generating network code.
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.Serialization.Weaver:WeaveUnetFromEditor(String,
>   String, String, String, Boolean)
>
> Error3: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Object' has
>   been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script
>   should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the
>   object. UnityEditor.Editor.IsEnabled () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/Editor.cs:589)
>   UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor editor,
>   Int32 editorIndex, Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean&
>   showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect)
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1151)
>   UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditors (UnityEditor.Editor[] editors)
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1028)
>   UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.OnGUI () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:352)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation for `SyncVar`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html), this line seems quite relevant:

> Only simple values can be marked as [SyncVars]. The type of the SyncVar variable cannot be from an external DLL or assembly.

As such, a generic `List` can't be marked as a `SyncVar`, because it's not contained within the Unity assembly. However, there are other options - Unity includes [several collection types](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetStateSync.html) that can be used for synchronizing across the network.

In your case, it sounds like you need the `SyncListStruct` collection, which allows you to synchronize a list of user-defined `struct` instances. (Of course, that means `RoomPlayerInfo` needs to be a `struct`, which may entail a bit of code rewrite.)

For example, your code might look like:

```
// Define a new class which inherits from the generic SyncListStruct
public class RoomPlayerInfoList : SyncListStruct<RoomPlayerInfo> {}

// [...]

public class PlayerNetworkingScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public RoomPlayerInfoList listRoomPlayerInfo = new RoomPlayerInfoList();

    // If necessary, define and attach a callback to the collection for when it changes
    private void RoomPlayerInfoListChanged(Operation op, int itemIndex) {
    }

    void Start() {
        listRoomPlayerInfo.Callback = RoomPlayerInfoListChanged;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.